# what is the IOPS behavior when partitions of single disk are used in an LVM?

Tags: linux, performance, performance-tuning, optimization, iops

I have an ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS server which have LVM(backed by hardware RAID5) with logical volume and a volume group named "dbstore-lv" and "dbstore-vg" which have sdb1 sdb2 sdb3 created from same sdb disk. The system as 42 cores and about 128G memory. Although i dont see CPU spikes in `htop` the load average output from `uptime` is ~43+  as well as vmstat shows constant iowait of 20-40 where the `context switches` is constantly around 80,000-150000 and even more at peak hours, the cpu idle time is also hovers around 70-85. Below is output of `iostat -xp 1` where the `%util` is constantly 100%

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           8.91    0.00    1.31   10.98    0.00   78.80

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00   264.00    0.00   58.00     0.00  1428.00    49.24     0.02    0.28    0.00    0.28   0.21   1.20
sda1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda2              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda3              0.00   264.00    0.00   58.00     0.00  1428.00    49.24     0.02    0.28    0.00    0.28   0.21   1.20
sdb               0.00   316.00    4.00   86.00   512.00  1608.00    47.11    36.02    0.27    5.00    0.05  11.11 100.00
sdb1              0.00   312.00    4.00   63.00   3512.00  4500.00    60.06    34.02    100.00    5.00    0.00  14.93 100.00
sdb2              0.00     0.00    0.00   821.00     450.00    84.00     8.00     82.00    99.19    0.00    0.19  47.62 100.00
sdb3              0.00     4.00    0.00    2.00     0.00    24.00    24.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-0              0.00     0.00    0.00    6.00     0.00    24.00     8.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-1              0.00     0.00    4.00  396.00   512.00  1584.00    10.48    36.02    8180.00  5.00   8180.00 2.50 100.00
dm-2              0.00     0.00    0.00  329.00     0.00  3896.00    23.68     0.85    2.58    0.00    2.58   0.05   1.60
dm-3              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

Similarly the TPS/iops is around 600-1000 most of the time(eg. iostat outptu below)

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          22.24    0.35    2.56   32.08    0.00   42.77

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sda             527.00      3828.00      1536.00       3828       1536
sdb             576.00      8532.00      2804.00       8532       2804
sdc              42.00       280.00       156.00        280        156
dm-0              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-1            956.00      8400.00      2804.00       8400       2804
dm-2            569.00      4108.00      1692.00       4108       1692
dm-3              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
```

Here is `vmstat 1` output

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 2 22 986520 621704 440356 23588860    0    0  2560  8140 27032 132198 16  2 46 36  0
 7 23 986520 672528 440204 23532752    0    0  2360     8 26659 107002 10  2 48 41  0
22 18 986520 697048 440084 23496096    0    0  3152 22520 60223 187651 25  5 46 25  0
 2 18 986520 688596 439984 23501104    0    0  2436   684 50451 210261 20  5 49 26  0
13 33 986520 663680 439984 23495812    0    0  1712 149956 38549 136294 15  4 45 36  0
 9 34 986520 647308 439968 23507944    0    0  1484  1832 51501 174355 19  4 38 39  0
14 18 986520 608364 439340 23531976   12    0  1828 21344 63692 134934 15  4 48 33  0
11 23 986520 588220 437636 23549852    0    0  2528   192 33461 116199 13  3 50 35  0
 3 17 986520 601892 438080 23542508    0    0  3224 16376 74679 167580 20  5 40 34  0
 1 16 986520 567092 438080 23574776    0    0  2272 76624 40944 136229 16  4 51 29  0
 6 16 986520 584120 438380 23560932    0    0 18568     0 32038 108119 12  3 56 29  0
17 17 986520 568012 438392 23575828    0    0  2572 67248 54320 168767 19  4 51 26  0
 5 23 986520 566384 438124 23575640    0    0  2656   360 60057 158031 18  5 49 28  0
 1 29 986520 632216 438604 23546316    0    0  2520 28528 49198 109391 10  4 50 37  0
19 14 986508 621236 438616 23560516    0    0  2528  9368 39632 169120 19  4 44 32  0
 8 31 986532 653172 440340 23548788   32    0  2460   208 29679 116036 14  4 42 40  0
28 26 986532 675568 440344 23551600    0    0  4552  3928 29385 113816 16  3 39 42  0
10 34 986532 654700 440352 23561616    0    0  2712   816 31667 155532 20  3 40 37  0
15 20 986520 630768 440356 23577388   32    0  4416  4348 35499 175319 30  3 35 32  0
```

Below is excerpt of `lsblk` which shows lvm associated to disks

```
sdb                                8:16   0  19.7T  0 disk
├─sdb1                             8:17   0   7.7T  0 part
│ └─dbstore-lv (dm-1)              252:1    0   9.4T  0 lvm  /var/db/st01
├─sdb2                             8:18   0   1.7T  0 part
│ └─dbstore-lv (dm-1)              252:1    0   9.4T  0 lvm  /var/db/st01
└─sdb3                             8:19   0  10.3T  0 part
  └─archive--archivedbstore--lv (dm-0)     252:0    0  10.3T  0 lvm  /opt/archive/
```

Queue Depth for sdb

```
cat /sys/block/sdb/device/queue_depth
1020
```

I am assuming this is due to disk seek problem as the same disk partitions are used for same LVM or may be its due to saturation of the disks(i dont have the vendor provided IOPS data of this disk yet). As initial tuning i have set vm.dirty_ratio to 5 and dirty_background_ratio to 2 + tried deadline scheduler (currently noop) but this doesnt seem to help to reduce the iowait. Any suggestions please ?

Comment: First try to find out if your storag is too slow by measuring the max throughput and IOPS.

Answer (score 0):

I'll propose do next step:

- check state of disk with smartctl
- install additional soft atop which can save historical output(also atop have different views, like top cpu, top memory, top usage disks) you can see what actively read/write on disk

@Christopher Perrin put good mention about test disk IOPS

Answer (score 0):

When all your storage bolumes are originated on a single volume, the I/O characteristics of your LVM are limited to what is the underlying RAID/HBA capable of.
Your `vmstat 1` screen is showing a very large amount of context switches.
Your pictures omit usage of `dm-0`, which may consume I/O bandwidth at HBA level.
With a proper storage array, SSD backed, you can easily reach 4k IOPS per LUN, take this into account.